# DAX Power BI occurrences of character in string

Tags: string, count, powerbi, dax, find-occurrences

-- my DAX formula is unable to count the occurrences of a "," (comma) in a string from Column2, in a specific "Category" row. --

Formula = CALCULATE(
COUNTAX( FILTER ('Query1', 'Query1'[Col1] = "Category", 'Query1'[Col2] = ",") )
)

-- Any suggestions? --

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following coulmn calculation to count the number of comma in a string:

```
Check = LEN(Query1[Col2])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Query1[Col2],",",""))
```

If you need the overall count, you can simply sum up the calculated field. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick without the need of a calculated column

```
Formula :=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( 'Query1', FIND ( ",", 'Query1'[Col1],, 0 ) > 0 ) ),
    'Query1'[Col2] = "Category"
)
```